# What is PageFactory in Selenium and what is the use of PageFactory.initElements(driver, this) statement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

Please can you explain What is PageFactory in Selenium and  what happen with `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)` statement, and also please explain differences b/w `By` and `@FindBy`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider researching on your own before asking at StackOverflow (see [ask]). Else your questions might get down-voted due to *lack of research*. Usually, such stuff is always explained by the project owners in their **documentation**. You can also find it with a simple google search like [selenium PageFactory](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+pagefactory) etc. After you have researched and read the docs, you can come back and ask a more specific question about the detail that is still unclear. Also consider creating examples to elaborate on your question more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PageFactory helps you in implementing PageObject model in Selenium Framework.

PageFactory.initElements(driver, this) statement initializes the page element so that you can work directly on the element without getting the NullPointerException (since the page object has been initialized implicitly).

More on this can be read in documentation with examples.https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory